# Fazer login com usuário ou e-mail no mesmo campo

Tags: php, mysql

Olá! Tenho um código de login mas, não consigo fazer com que o usuário possa logar com seu e-mail ou nome de usuário usando o mesmo campo! Abaixo segue meu código, o e-mail na minha data base está com nome "mail".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem sua pergunta e seu código, é só você colocar um `OR`:

```
$userq = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE (username = '{HoloText($_POST['credentials_username'])}' OR mail='$email') AND password = '$pwd' LIMIT 1");
```

Dica: As vezes usar o [javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/zt3ycx6w/) para fazer uma validação dos campos fica melhor e mais simples.

Comment: Pq o _limit 1_? Não basta verificar se existe ou não?

Comment: @DavidSamm Foi C&P do código do AP.

Answer (score 0):

Para que você consiga *logar* com *username* e *email* ao mesmo tempo, você deve acrescentar na sua *query* um OR. Exemplo

```
SELECT username, password FROM users 
WHERE (username = "usernameRecebido" OR email = "emailRecebido") 
AND password = "passwordRecebido"
```